# Call to a member function bindParam() what?

Tags: php

My php code is given below.

```
class Login {

    public function logar($login, $senha){
        $db = new Database();
        try{
            $conn = $db->connect();
            $prepare = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE Login = :login AND Passwd = :senha");
            $prepare->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->execute();
            $ranking = $prepare->rowCount();
            if ($ranking >= 1){
                return "<div class='n_ok' style='margin:9px 15px;'><p>Successfully.</p></div>";
            }else{
                return "<div class='n_error' style='margin:9px 15px;'><p>Usuario ou senha incorreta.</p></div>";
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

While i am running this below error is occured

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in C:\AppServ\www\class\Login.class.php on line 9**

Comment: `prepare` method returns false when an error occurred, it seems that there is some issue with your database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "new Database()" refer to. I hope it should return PDO Connection.

Below Code will work fine for sure

```
class Login {
    public function logar($login, $senha){
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=dbhostname;dbname=databasename', $user, $pass);
        try{
            $prepare = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE Login = :login AND Passwd = :senha");
            $prepare->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->execute();
            $ranking = $prepare->rowCount();
            if ($ranking >= 1){
                return "<div class='n_ok' style='margin:9px 15px;'><p>Successfully.</p></div>";
            }else{
                return "<div class='n_error' style='margin:9px 15px;'><p>Usuario ou senha incorreta.</p></div>";
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare could return false, 
Always close your previous statement with

```
$statement->close();
```

If the syntax is correct, the following query will run well too.

Comment: Also make sure error reporting is on: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Still the same mistake remains

Comment: try to add this if (!$prepare) {
        echo "false";
    }
    else {
  $prepare->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $prepare->execute();
 }